# Two of the same directories on remote with different cases while only one locally

Tags: git

I have two of the same directories on remote. `app/Helpers` and `app/helpers`. Locally on the same branch I only have `app/helpers`.

How do I get out of this mess and keep uppercase `app/Helpers` on both local and remote, and remove lowercase `app/helpers` from both?

I intended to rename `helpers` directory to uppercase on first letter, but since windows is case insensitive I changed `git config core.ignorecase` to **false** to be able to do it. Sadly after I commited and pushed the changes it made both on remote and somehow I have only the lowercase locally now after changing `git config core.ignorecase` back to **true**.

Comment: Rename one of them on the remote that handles casing, commit that and then pull to local.

Comment: If you intended the two folders to be the same, again on that remove, move all the content of the incorrect folder into the other one, delete the incorrect folder, commit that, and then pull to local.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen now I have only `app/Helpers` on remote, but after pulling to local I don't have helpers directory locally at all. Fetching doesnt get it either.

Comment: Never mind, It was unstaged "deleted" locally after pulling. Got it sorted out. You can post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only know of one way of fixing a casing issue like that, and that is by fixing it on a remote that supports case differences.

In other words, on the remote you have 2 folders, you can do one of the following, depending on how you want the end result to be:

1. If you want the two folders to stay separate, rename one of them so that it has a different name, other than just a case difference.
2. If you want the two folders to be just one, combine the contents into the one folder you want to keep, that is, the one with the right casing in its name. Note that depending on how you ended up in the situation you're in, the contents of the two folders might be different, they might be the same, or there may be a mix of files existing in both and files only existing in one of them.

After you've performed one or the other, commit, and share this new commit with your local clone.

**Note:** This will **not** fix the history. If you ever check out one of the flawed commits in your history, you might have problems again. If you want to fix that you need to rewrite history to get rid of the casing problem altogether.

**Note:** Also, make sure you fix the local folder to have the correct casing as well, or you might end up reintroducing the problem in your next commits. If you don't have uncommitted changes, it might be best to just wipe the local clone and reclone to make sure it is correctly in sync with the remote.

Answer (score 0):

Do a 2 step renaming of your directory like described in this blog post and you should be good.

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/GitIsCasesensitiveAndYourFilesystemMayNotBeWeirdFolderMergingOnWindows.aspx

Unfortunately, your history won't be fixed (and I think it doesn't worth to do it)

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do it:

1. Go to GitHub (I suppose the same logic works in other CVS frontends too)
2. Go to your working branch, if that's where you want to delete them
3. Open the directory that is duplicated and **should** be deleted
4. On the top right corner, there is the three-dots-menu, which has the option "Delete directory"
5. Press it
6. On the page that opens, scroll to the bottom and add a commit message + press Commit
7. Then pull the changes to your local